# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username') php

Tags: javascript

In the process of designing the login page, I encountered a weave of challenges and achievements. The expected outcome was for the user to see relevant information upon successful login, be directed to the "welcome.html" page, and have their username displayed. However, I faced an issue while implementing this.

In my system, there are two sets of user data. Everything worked as expected when using the first set of user data for login. However, when attempting to log in with the second set, an error occurred: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')". This error indicates that the username property cannot be read when processing the second set of user data.

During debugging, I noticed that the first set of user data is an array, while the second set is an object. To address this issue, I need to adjust my code to ensure that whether it is an array or an object, the user is successfully navigated to the "welcome.html" page, and the username is correctly displayed on that page.

I will take some measures to handle this situation, such as checking the type of user data to determine the correct method for accessing properties. In this way, I expect to smoothly implement the design of the login page and ensure the correct display of the user's username on the "welcome.html" page. Thank you for your attention and support; I will continue to work on resolving this issue for an enhanced user experience.

```js
 const loginForm = document.querySelector("#login-form");
        const registerForm = document.querySelector("#register-form");

        function login(e){
            const formData = new FormData(loginForm);
            let body = {};
            formData.forEach((key, index) => {
                body[index] = key;
            });

            console.log(body);
            e.preventDefault();
            fetch('/apis/users/login.php', {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            }).then(r =>{
                return r.json()
            }).then(r => {
                console.log(r);
                if(r.status == 1){
                    sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(r));
                    alert("Login successful");
                    location.href = "/views/welcome.html";
                } else {
                    alert(r.msg);
                }
            })
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome Back:<span id="user"></span>
</body>
<script>
    const data = sessionStorage.getItem("user") ? JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user')):undefined;
    console.log(data);
    if(!data){
        alert("Please Login");
        location.href = "/views/index.html";
    }else{
        document.querySelector("#user").innerHTML = data.user[0].username;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add HTML code you have written or stackblitz

Comment: none of that code is trying to read a property called `username` ... are you sure you've posted the right code regarding the error?

Comment: Could the issue be that you're sending JSON, but haven't set the content-type to reflext that?

Comment: Please add all details and relevant code *inside* the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77904143/edit) - [ask] - How to create a [mre]

Comment: @Bhavy - Don't ask to provide an external snippet. (Especially not when the problem is justing revoling around JS and could be recreated by the tools provided by SO). Relevant code should be posted together with the question

Comment: in that case `data.user[0]` is undefined ... check your `data` - is it an array?